# Is there any way to get current pointer position in tkinter scrolledtext widget

Tags: python-3.x, performance, user-interface, tkinter, text-widget

I am new on tkinter I am confused with scrolledtext widget my doubt is
Is there any way to get current pointer position in tkinter scrolledtext widget!!

Comment: `.focus_set()` is what you are looking for

Comment: @FrainBr33z3: no, that won't return the pointer or cursor. It simply sets the focus.

Comment: Do you really mean the _pointer_ position, or the insertion cursor? What do you need the pointer position for?

Comment: I want only pointer position

Comment: Thanks both  of you but I got my answer !!

Comment: It's was INSERT constant of tkinter which solved my problem

Comment: So, you aren't looking for the _pointer_ position, but rather then position of the insertion cursor? The pointer and the cursor are two different things.